# npm Grunt loads, but then grunt command unrecognized

Tags: javascript, command-line, npm, gruntjs

I have used grunt on this computer before for other projects (4 months ago), and recently wanted to use grunt for a new project. I loaded grunt globally and then locally, but after that typing in $ grunt -v says grunt is not recognized as if it is not loaded, or perhaps the path is wrong? anyone got any ideas? 
[image]

Update: 5/16/2016, I tried the below suggestion and loaded casper-cli globally and locally, and the grunt command still fails. Additionally, I tried another command 'casperjs' and that one is also failing even though that has worked perfectly for the last year or so. It appears all of my commands are not working anymore, what could possibly cause that?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You have to install the grunt-cli globally to use grunt in the console:
`npm install grunt-cli -g`

Comment: If you don't want to install globally, also a simple script in package.json calling grunt will work